# Not understandable behavior when waitingAsync SemaphoreSlim

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, async-await, semaphore

I am trying sending email using this code

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                var sendResponse = emailService.SendEmailAsync(builder => builder

                .To("abdelrahman@ogtech.com", "Abdelrahman")
                .Subject("Your Invoice Ready " + i.ToString())
                .Body("this is to inform you that yoyr invoice is ready " + i.ToString())

                );

                await Task.Delay(10);
            }


public async Task<SendResponse> SendEmailAsync(Action<EmailMessageInfoBuilder> builderAction)
        {
            await _lock.WaitAsync();

            SendResponse sendResponse = null;
            EmailMessageInfo emailInfo = null;
            try
            {
                
                EmailMessageInfoBuilder emailInfoBuilder = new EmailMessageInfoBuilder(_fluentEmailFactory);
                builderAction(emailInfoBuilder);

                emailInfo = emailInfoBuilder.EmailMessageInfo;

                IFluentEmail fluentEmail = CreateFluentEmail(emailInfo);
                
                sendResponse = await fluentEmail.SendAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger?.LogError(ex, $"Faild to send Email {emailInfo?.ToJSON()}");
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.Release();
            }

            return sendResponse;


        }
```

The _lock object is defined as following:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

Very strange behavior occurring, I received one email with

subject => "Your Invoice Ready 1"
and body => "this is to inform you that yoyr invoice is ready 1"

and 9 emails with the subject

subject => "Your Invoice Ready 11"
and body => "this is to inform you that yoyr invoice is ready 11"

Any suggestions on why this result?

Note: when I remove the lines

```
await _lock.WaitAsync();
_lock.Release();
```

it working normally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp) You have captured `i` in the lambda, not the value of `i`. You need to assign it to a separate variable

Comment: Other issues: Your use of `async` is strange. You are calling `SendEmailAsync` but then ignoring the resulting task (and any exception) and instead delaying 10ms. So this shouldn't even need a locking mechanism: just await the result of each call of `SendEmailAsync` with `await`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks a lot, the issue is exactly as you pointed, capturing i in the lambda was the issue. Thanks again